# How to print out the exact field/string of the JSON output?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter all the result that I got in the GET Request.
The Output that I want is just to get the **summary: , key: and self:**.
But I'm getting a lot of Json data.
I've tried googling on how to do this and I'm going to nowhere.

Here is my code:
The commented lines are the codes that I have tried.

```
import requests
import json
import re
import sys
url ="--------"
auth='i.g--t----------', 'X4------'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(auth))
data = r.json()
#print( json.dumps(data, indent=2) )
#res1 = " ".join(re.split("summary", data))
#print ("first string result: ", str(res1))
#json_str = json.dumps(data)
#resp = json.loads(json_str)
#print (resp['id'])
#resp_dict = json.loads(resp_str)
#resp_dict.get('name')
#print('dasdasd', json_str["summary"])
```

Example of the Get Api Output that I'm getting using this code. `print( json.dumps(data, indent=2) )`

```
 {
      "id": "65621",
      "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/65621",
      "key": "CMS-5901",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "new starter: Edoardo Bologna",
        "customfield_10700": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "BBOXX Rwanda HQ",
            "_links": {
              "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/organization/2"
            }
          }
 },
            "inwardIssue": {
              "id": "65862",
              "key": "BMT-2890",
              "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/65862",
              "fields": {
                "summary": "ERP Databases access with Read Only",
                "status": {
                  "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10000",
                  "description": "",
                  "iconUrl": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/",
                  "name": "To Do",
                  "id": "10000",
                  "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
                    "id": 2,
                    "key": "new",
                    "colorName": "blue-gray",
                    "name": "To Do"
                  }
                },
                "priority": {
                  "self": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/4",
                  "iconUrl": "https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/low.svg",
                  "name": "Low",
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/IanJayloG/Desktop/Python Files/Ex_Files_Learning_Python/Exercise Files/Test/Untitled-1.py", line 17, in <module>
    print('dasdasd', data["summary"])
KeyError: 'summary'
PS C:\Users\IanJayloG\Desktop\Python Files\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files> & C:/Users/IanJayloG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe "c:/Users/IanJayloG/Desktop/Python Files/Ex_Files_Learning_Python/Exercise Files/Test/Untitled-1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/IanJayloG/Desktop/Python Files/Ex_Files_Learning_Python/Exercise Files/Test/Untitled-1.py", line 17, in <module>
    print('dasdasd', json_str["summary"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem about your error message

```
  print('dasdasd', json_str["summary"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

is that you try to access the named field `summary` on a string (variable `json_str`), which does not work because strings don't have fields to access by name. If you use the indexing `[]` operator on a string, you can only provide integers or ranges to extract single characters or sequences from that string. This is obviously not what you're intending.

The keys `self` and `key` are on top level of your JSON document, whereas `summary` is under `fields`. This should do it, without any extra transformation applied:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url, auth=(auth))
data = r.json()

data_summary = data['fields']['summary']
data_self = data['self']
data_key = data['key']
```

Comment: Hi @jbndlr thank you for your response. But still, I received an error.
`KeyError: 'fields'`